# is arrayObject.length = 0 clears the memory allocated for arrayObject?

Tags: javascript

If yes then how it is different from using `arrayObject = []`. Is this 2 things are different or 2 ways of doing the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
array.length = 0;
```

keeps the object reference to the original array.

```
array = [];
```

creates a new object reference.

Comment: A nice update to your answer would be showing this effect.  Eg. `b = a, a.length=0; log(a===b), a=[], log(a===b) ==> true, false`

Comment: Then it is better to use length property to clear the array. am I right?. For the cases like, we need to clear the array with in a loop every time before usage.

Comment: @Robert, it depends on the use case. if you need it in a loop, you could take a local variable inside of the loop, eg `const array = []`.

Comment: If you have references to this array, yes.  If not it's not likely to make much difference.

Answer (score 0):

Yes looks like it does clear out the memory.

`a=[]` will create a new reference for an empty array.

```js
let a = [1, 2, 3];

a.length = 0;

console.log(a);

a.length = 2;

console.log(a);
```